# Excel com senha para edição

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel, password

Estou montando um arquivo Excel onde eu gero um array de bytes e a UI faz o download do arquivo no formato xlsx, preciso abrir esse arquivo com senha para realizar edições, existe uma forma de fazer isso direto no array de bytes ?

Comment: Poste o seu código, não entendi uma coisa, você quer criar um arquivo protegido por senha ou quer abrir um?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu quero criar um arquivo protegido por senha, eu preciso conseguir abrir esse arquivo mas não posso deixar o usuário editar esse arquivo.
o unico código que tenho é o código que faz download do ByteArray no formato xls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232899/4713574

Comment: Seguindo a recomendação do @RovannLinhalis, lembre-se de que precisará ter o Office instalado na máquina onde a aplicação estiver rodando.